# Styling Table in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to give backgrounds to columns and change font styling of table in UI5 using javascript and css. 
I need to know how do I reach a particular element if CSS has to be applied to it.
How do it I do that?

Comment: give table a class by addclass() method and do whatever you want as usual in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class on your table or column whereever you want as

```
oTable.addStyleClass("classname");
```

use css as usual

```
.classname{
color:red
}
```

and include this css file in index.html

Based on your comment: to add id to table header column use it in this way

```
var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column("tc",{
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Last Name"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "lastName"),
    sortProperty: "lastName",
    filterProperty: "lastName",
    width: "200px"
});
```

Here `id=tc` is added to this header.

write css as you need

```
#tc{
color:red
}
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qAnB2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help Roshan... what I really wanted to do was give the rows in the table alterbate colors using nth child in css... how do i give the rows a class / target rows in the oTable for specific CSS...

Comment: Thanks buddy... gr8 help.. but how to style the header i.e. column heading...tr and td work fine... th is not working... how do i do that?

Comment: if the solution solved your query you can accept the answer(by selecting the green tick mark), or else if you have something else you can ask that too. :)

Answer (score 0):

==================xml===================================

===================format js===========================

```
yaoji.utils.formatter.format = function (cellValue) {
     this.onAfterRendering= function() {
     //!!! if not after redering, can't get the dom
        var cellId = this.getId(); 
        $("#"+cellId).parent().parent().parent().css("background-color","red"); 
     return cellValue;
};
```